# PSD Artboards Script to change Smartobject and Save Artboards to Files

Tags: javascript, automation, scripting, psd

I'm trying to automate a task in Photoshop using a script, but I'm having trouble getting it to work as expected. Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

I have a Photoshop file with 48 artboards, each with a different name.
Each artboard has a smart object layer called "Artwork" that's linked to eachother, normally if I change one, all of them changes. So I would like this script to take designs from a folder and run it by replacing it with a new image.
After replacing the smart object content, I want to export each artboard as a JPEG file with a quality of 5, and save it in a separate folders named after the design file, followed by the artboard name.

I found a script online that almost does what I need, but it's not working as expected. It's giving me an error message "No artboard named found in the active document". I also tried another script that lists all artboards, but it's not showing any artboards in my document.

Can someone help me modify the script to achieve my goal? I'm not very experienced with scripting, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

This is the original video I found the info: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-t8zcTfiG7c&ab_channel=Alek

The original script: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fLKSJHkUp4TRGBQ6qL4f7PBbPH__cUcv/view

Then I said, let's only change the first artboards smartobject, and entered it's name, hoping it would find it... with the help of chatgbt..

```
#target photoshop

function main() {
    if (app.documents.length === 0) {
        alert('There are no documents open.');
        return;
    }

    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var artboard = findArtboard(doc.layerSets, "FSEMPVS semi transparent vellum invitation silver foil pressed");

    if (!artboard) {
        alert('No artboard named "FSEMPVS semi transparent vellum invitation silver foil pressed" found in the active document.');
        return;
    }

    var layer = findSmartObjectLayer(artboard.layers, "Artwork");

    if (!layer) {
        alert('No smart object layer named "Artwork" found in the specified artboard.');
        return;
    }

    var folder = Folder.selectDialog("Choose a folder to save the images");
    if (!folder) return;

    var artboards = getArtboards(doc);
    if (artboards.length === 0) {
        alert('No artboards found in the active document.');
        return;
    }

    replaceSmartObjectContent(layer, artboard);
    for (var i = 0; i < artboards.length; i++) {
        saveArtboardAsJPEG(doc, artboards[i], folder);
    }

    alert('Artboards exported successfully.');
}

function findArtboard(layerSets, targetName) {
    for (var i = 0; i < layerSets.length; i++) {
        var layerSet = layerSets[i];
        if (layerSet.artboardEnabled && layerSet.name === targetName) {
            return layerSet;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function findSmartObjectLayer(layers, targetName) {
    for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
        var layer = layers[i];
        if (layer.typename === 'ArtLayer' && layer.kind === LayerKind.SMARTOBJECT && layer.name === targetName) {
            return layer;
        } else if (layer.typename === 'LayerSet') {
            var result = findSmartObjectLayer(layer.layers, targetName);
            if (result) return result;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function replaceSmartObjectContent(layer, artboard) {
    var idplacedLayerReplaceContents = stringIDToTypeID("placedLayerReplaceContents");
    var desc3 = new ActionDescriptor();
    desc3.putPath(charIDToTypeID("null"), new File(artboard));
    executeAction(idplacedLayerReplaceContents, desc3, DialogModes.NO);
}

function getArtboards(doc) {
    var artboards = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < doc.layerSets.length; i++) {
        if (doc.layerSets[i].artboardEnabled) {
            artboards.push(doc.layerSets[i]);
        }
    }
    return artboards;
}

function saveArtboardAsJPEG(doc, artboard, folder) {
    var artboardRect = artboard.bounds;
    var exportOptions = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb();
    exportOptions.format = SaveDocumentType.JPEG;
    exportOptions.quality = 5;

    var fileName = doc.name.replace(/\.[^\.]+$/, '') + '_' + artboard.name
```

I was expecting the script would run, but no artboards can be found :/